# Handling data from option select forms in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, plotly

I have this select form:

```
  <div class="control">
        <div class="select">
          <select v-model="chart.traces">
             <option v-for="option in options" v- bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option> 
           </select>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Which gets data in the component:

```
data() {
    return {
      options:[
        {text: "Financial Condition", value: [ {
            x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
            y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Companies'
          }, {
            x: [5],
            y: [8],
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Checked'
          }
            ]},
        {text: "Ebitda", value: [ {
            x: [2, 1, 3, 6],
            y: [11, 12, 12, 17],
            mode: 'markers',
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Companies'
          }]
        }
      ]
```

Now I need to push this data depends on what is selected to the another data object inside the component:

```
traces: []
```

However somehow the `traces` object is not being populated based on what is selected.
Here is Codepen where you can check what is happening:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/pokepim/pen/ZEGzwrJ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo there : `v- bind:value="option.value"`.

It should be like that `v-bind:value="option.value"`

```html
  <div class="control">
    <div class="select">
      <select v-model="chart.traces">
        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```